# Deriving p of a Bernoulli trial from number of successes observed

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

I have conducted $20$ Bernoulli trials. My observed outcome is $8$ successes.

It was proposed that $p_\text{suc}$ was $0.2.$ I have calculated the standard deviation as $\sqrt{npq} = \sqrt{20\times0.2\times0.8} = \sqrt{3.2} = 1.79$

The proposed mean was $4,$ so my observed value is therefore $+ 2.22$ standard deviations, and so my p value is $0.0264.$ So this is significant by my measure ($<0.05$). However is it valid to say that there is a $97.4\%$ chance that $p_\text{suc} > 0.2$?

Also, I want to define a range of values for $p_\text{suc}$ given my observed number of successes, which I can be $95\%$ confident in. So my estimate is $8/20 = 0.4 \pm x$.

Is there a way to calculate $x$, or can I use brute force to simulate $20$ trials say $10,000+$ times for different $p_\text{suc}$ values, and use an algorithm to find the upper and lower cut-off values for $p_\text{suc}$ whereby my observed success count of 8 appears in $< 5\%$ of simulations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the frequentist perspective to hypothesis testing, $p_{\text{suc}}$ is not a random variable; it is a parameter whose value is **fixed** but unknown.  Thus it makes no sense to say $\Pr[p_{\text{suc}} > 0.2] = 0.974$.  All that the frequentist can say amounts to inferences about the true value of the fixed parameter based on the evidence shown in the **random** data.  So when the frequentist calculates a $p$-value, it is a probability of observing a result as extreme as the data obtained, if we suppose the null hypothesis is true; hence, the $p$-value is a measure of the implausibility of observing such data by random chance, not a measure of the chance of the parameter being in a certain interval.

For a binomial proportion, construction of a confidence interval for the parameter is not unique: there are several methods, each with advantages and disadvantages.  The simplest is based on a normal approximation and is the Wald interval; the most conservative is the Clopper-Pearson exact interval, which guarantees the nominal coverage probability, but can be unnecessarily large under certain conditions.  Another one is the Wilson score interval.